# Where's this Japanese-student-looking winged girl from?

Tags: story-identification, character-identification, art

Google Images is no help, while [Tineye](https://tineye.com/) reveals that this image of a non-human girl with dragon wings, blue skin, red eyes, horns and a tail, wearing what looks like a Japanese school uniform, given how it features a black armband, is confirmed from before 2009 and [probably](https://neshvacena.blogger.ba/2006/04/06/skola-down/) from before 2006 as well.

It has been [confirmed by Valorum](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13828/would-asking-to-identify-a-manga-drawing-guide-be-off-topic?noredirect=1#comment48581_13828) to not be in "Super Manga Matrix".

[Saucenao](https://saucenao.com/) highly implies that it's not from any Hentai, nor pixiv, DoujinshiDB, drawr, Nijie, yande.re, Shutterstock, FAKKU, MediBang, Gelbooru, Konachan, Sankaku Channel, Anime-Pictures.net, e621.net, Idol Complex, bcy.net Illust, bcy.net Cosplay, PortalGraphics.net, deviantArt, Pawoo.net, Madokami (Manga), MangaDex, ArtStation, FurAffinity, Twitter, Furry Network, Kemono, or Skeb.

[IQDB, the Multi-service image search](https://iqdb.org), implies that it's not on Danbooru, e-shuushuu or Zerochan either.

[image: Cute Monster Girl]

But it might just be sufficiently unsimilar to known images in a way that evades SauceNAO's detection, such as the Clements Twins. [DeviantArt](https://www.deviantart.com/mmbseven/art/World-s-Most-Beautiful-Twins-864553209) vs. [advertisement](https://media.revcontent.com/content/images/630bec0bb83867-74209559.jpg). We humans can tell, but SauceNAO can't.

Comment: As per this [meta question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13828/would-asking-to-identify-a-manga-drawing-guide-be-off-topic) it looks like the community (so far) and at least two mods (myself and TLC) agree it's on-topic. If you do disagree, please post your reasoning on that meta so we can discuss it there.

Comment: Looking at the joints on the wings, tail, and the horns, they look mechanical to me. She also appears to be wearing goggles or a face shield like on a helmet and maybe a headset or hearing protection, its possible she is wearing a mechanical/artificial horned headset, wings and tail. Unless they are armored at the weak points of real parts.

Comment: @NJohnny - Humans don't normally have blue skin and red eyes though. And those aren't goggles, they're half-moon glasses.

Comment: @Valorum: Eh, I hate doing this Val (massive respect fam), but rather than "goggles" or "half moon glasses", it's a visor. It's part of the head gear she's wearing, runs from one side of the helmet to the other, and goes up a little at the nose, making it look somewhat like half moon glasses.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier - I believe you to be incorrect. If we colour the lenses in, you can see that they're glasses, not a visor; https://i.stack.imgur.com/HA9vx.png. What you've mistaken for a helmet is a pair of hipster headphones

Comment: @Valorum: Now I can see both (it's like one of those optical illusion pictures where you see the pretty girl and the old crone), I see the curl of the upper rim of the glasses against her right eye. I should have known better :)

Comment: @Valorum I remember reading that people with albinism can appear to have red eyes because of the lack of pigments and with specific lightnings. Other than that, I agree for the rest.

Comment: Could be Danganronpa https://www.reddit.com/r/danganronpa/comments/ir289z/danganronpa_characters_but_they_are_a_badly_made/

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi Hmm, it looks like Danganronpa came out in 2010, and this specific image has been circulating on Internet since at least 2008 according to a TinEye search. And according to the comments of this DeviantArt https://static.tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pub/images/Maestesized.jpg (they admitted it's not theirs), it was added on TvTropes before the 2008 Great Crash

Comment: I tried looking at the file's metadata/EXIF in case it might contain anything useful. The only thing I could find is it was cropped using an online website (which you can guess from the file name in the link: "Maestesized.jpg").

Comment: One more possible character "trickywi" https://twitter.com/trickywii/status/1527459229564653570

Comment: My bad, this is the DeviantArt link I mentioned earlier (copy-pasted the link of the picture itself): https://www.deviantart.com/alicethegorgon/art/Have-you-seen-me-143572832

Comment: I can see the possibility of the half moon glasses, but the lines are barely there enough that it could be debatable. But I do now see a microphone on right side of her head that I had not noticed before. And as opposed to Ski Googles I thought of it more as a full face shield like on Pilots helmets. So to me, with the rest of the mechanical appearance of the items (Tail, wings, horns) I think she could be wearing a helmet with horns, mic, face shield attached.

Comment: The fact that it's on a white background makes me pretty certain this is somebody's original character.

Comment: Found an earlier copy, so circulating since at least 2006: https://neshvacena.blogger.ba/2006/04/06/skola-down/#comments

Comment: @Tragamor - The image's url having 2021 in it makes me suspicious: https://neshvacena.blogger.ba/wp-content/uploads/sites/9069/2021/05/14711.206513.jpg - But might just be coincidence, the site having no new posts since 2006. - Might just be due to Blogger updating things automatically. - web.archive.org/web/20070315080110/http://neshvacena.blogger.ba:80/

Comment: You might be able to search for this image on google. It will likely turn up with many results. Basically - search "search image on google", and then click "Google Images". From there, upload or add an image.

Comment: @Silvermidnight - I should've said that I used that too, huh. I guess my other methods aren't clearly overlapping.

Comment: It looks to me like some kind of Blue Oni/Red Oni trope, seeing as how it's blue but with a red dress. I would bet she has a counterpart that is red with a blue dress.

Comment: Sorry, I should have read the text better. Did Google Image Search work though?

Comment: @Silvermidnight - Updated the question. It was "no help". There's no different sizes and no similar images are the same image.

Comment: Has a Range Murata vibe to it, but not quite. Be warned that Murata approaches NSFW.